# Swagger-php how to specify key => typed value pairs?

Tags: php, openapi, swagger-php

I'm stuck when trying to define settings API documentation. Let's say, that in

```
 @OA\JsonContent()
```

I need to have two properties - **key** and **value**. But properties are strictly defined as

key => type of the value

```
scoring.password.length => boolean
scoring.entity.device => boolean
scoring.twofactor_when_score_gte => integer
```

How to write @OA\Property for this pairs?

I've tried e.g. this, but it is not ideal as value is key-independent and in Redocly it looks really terrible (an key names are not visible):

```
@OA\RequestBody(
*         required=true,
*         description="Pass setting key-value pair",
*         @OA\JsonContent(
*              required={"key", "value"},
*              @OA\Property(property="key", type="object",
*                  @OA\AdditionalProperties(type="array",
*                    @OA\Items(oneOf={
*                          @OA\Property(property="scoring.password.length", type="bool"),
*                          @OA\Property(property="scoring.password.complexity.symbols", type="bool"),
*                          @OA\Property(property="scoring.password.complexity.mixed_case", type="bool"),
*                          @OA\Property(property="scoring.password.leaks", type="bool"),
*                          @OA\Property(property="scoring.password.complexity.letters", type="bool"),
*                          @OA\Property(property="scoring.password.complexity.numbers", type="bool"),
*                          @OA\Property(property="scoring.entity.device", type="bool"),
*                          @OA\Property(property="scoring.entity.geodata", type="bool"),
*                          @OA\Property(property="scoring.entity.disposable_email", type="bool"),
*                          @OA\Property(property="scoring.entity.leaks.phone", type="bool"),
*                          @OA\Property(property="scoring.entity.leaks.email", type="bool"),
*                          @OA\Property(property="scoring.entity.blacklist", type="bool"),
*                          @OA\Property(property="scoring.twofactor_when_score_gte", type="integer"),
*                          @OA\Property(property="scoring.disallow_when_score_gte", type="integer"),
*                          @OA\Property(property="deny_login.blacklist.email", type="bool"),
*                          @OA\Property(property="deny_login.blacklist.domain", type="bool"),
*                          @OA\Property(property="deny_login.blacklist.ip", type="bool"),
*                      }
*                    )
*                  ),
*              ),
*              @OA\Property(property="value", type="string", description="The value of the setting (int|string|bool)"),
*         ),
```

[Redocly representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibmy0.png)

Comment: How is the settings JSON supposed to look like? Is it an array of objects `[ {"key": "scoring.password.length", "value": true}, {... other settings} ]` or a dict/map `{"scoring.password.length": true, "scoring.entity.device": true, ...}`?

Comment: always only one pair {"scoring.password.length": true} or {"scoring.twofactor_when_score_gte": 50} or ...